# How to print a code inside javascript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript loop and I want to display my html code inside it, like if I use `echo` in PHP, the code prints there. This is what I have tried so far:

```
<div class="colorpick">
    <script language="javascript">
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        domument.write('<div class="pick" style="background-color:'+ list[i] + '" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor);"></div>');
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: no I did not get any error.

Comment: no error no question just a demo then?

Comment: It's `document.write`, not `domument.write`. And yes, you **were** getting an error. Open your web console.

Comment: If you looking to print the chunk inside your loop. Then you may look at using the HTML pre element like http://infoheap.com/pre-tag-to-display-code/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try{
   var strContent = "";
   for( var i=0; i<2; i++ ) {
       strContent += "<div class=\"pick\" style=\"background-color:" + list[i] + "\" onclick=\"hello(this.style.backgroundColor);\"></div>";
   }
   document.write(strContent);
} catch(ex) {
   alert(ex);
}
```

The exception handler is just there to let you know if something else is wrong.

Comment: Thankyou. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Just blindly throwing an error handler around it is not a solution. The solution was actually buried in there: It's a simple typo correction.

Comment: The exception handler was added to give some indication of what is going wrong, not to fix the issue.

Comment: Then the answer isn't an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: Does what I posted work?  Yes, the posted code shows how to find and resolve issues like this with proper error handling.

Answer (score 1):

The original code had a typo (domument - which is why it wasn't working), but you can do this more efficiently with jQuery (since your question is tagged with jQ) - loop through your list and then append it to the div in the HTML - Note that I added a bg- class to each div with the color listed.

This allows an external CSS approach to the styling of the divs, rather than inline styling that you had. It is much better to keep the CSS out of the HTML if you can. Same with the javascript - removing from the HTML and adding it into the script via an event handler allows for better code structure.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var str="";
  var list=["red","green","blue"];
  
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      str += "<div class='pick bg-"+ list[i] +"'>Click Me</div>";
    }
  
     $('.colorpick').append(str);

     $('.pick').on('click',function(){alert($(this).css('background-color'))});

})
```

```css
.bg-red{background:red}
.bg-green{background:green}
.bg-blue{background:blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colorpick"></div>
```